# Pointers: What does this line of code mean?

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I'm new to programming, but have an internship this summer and I'm trying to get this code to run.

I'm going through someone else's c++ code ("Exact Geodesic for Triangular Meshes" open source) and one line is tripping me up. Anyway, the line is as follows:

```
geodesic::Mesh* mesh = algorithms[algorithm_id]->mesh();
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but first a pointer is being initialized. It looks like

```
class::pointerclass* thingpointedto = something[something] accessing member mesh();
```

I have no clue what the code on the right side of the equals operand means. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Do you have a typo? The pointer to member operator `->` **can't** have a space.

Comment: `algorithms` is an array/vector/map (or some other type with an overloaded `operator[]`). It apparently returns a pointer to something with a `mesh()` member, which returns another pointer.

Comment: `algorithm` is an array of algorithms. `algorithm_id` is an index (the number of an algorithm over all the provided ones), so you get first a given algorithm. Once you get one algorithm (beware it is just a pointer to an algorithm), you just call its method `mesh()` which send you back the address of some computed `Geodesic::Mesh` structure.

Comment: I had hard time trying to understand second bold line, but the first bold line  means (assuming it is correctly compiled) that 1) there is an array called `algorithms` of pointers to object of some class (not specified here) 2) that class has member function `mesh()` that returns pointer to an object of class `geodesic::Mesh` 3) this line of code defines a pointer to `geodesic::Mesh` called `mesh` and initializes it with result of method 'mesh()` called using `algorithm_id`th pointer of array `algorithms`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a look at the potential [source](https://github.com/bobye/tri-mesh-toolkit/blob/master/include/geodesic/geodesic_matlab_api.cpp#L115) I would say it is an `std::vector<algorithm_shared_pointer>`. Where `algorithm_shared_pointer` is a typedef for `boost::shared_ptr<geodesic::GeodesicAlgorithmBase>`.

```
geodesic::Mesh* mesh = algorithms[algorithm_id]->mesh();
```

`geodesic` is a namespace and the `Mesh` class is located in that namespace. We create a pointer to that class. The pointer is assigned the result of the function call `mesh()` which can be invoked by `geodesic::GeodesicAlgorithmBase`. The `algorithm_id` is an `int` which is provided as a parameter to the function which contains this line.

This integer is used to select the index in the vector.

---

Which would result in:

```
namespace::pointerToClass* nameOfPointer 
    = std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<geodesic::GeodesicAlgorithmBase>>[int]->mesh();
```

Which is an odd piece of code considering it could have used `auto` due to the `mesh()` return type being `geodesic::Mesh*`.

Answer (score 2):

```
geodesic::Mesh* mesh = algorithms[algorithm_id]->mesh();
```

Here, `algorithms` could either be a type of:

- An array pointer, in which case it is indexed by an *integral* type integer, `algorithm_id`
- A sequential container  with an overload `operator[]`, eg `std:vector` that is indexed with an integral type integer,  `algorithm_id`
- An Associative container with an overloaded `operator []`, e.g `std::map`, that is indexed with a key type object, `algorithm_id`
- A Custom Type with an overloaded `operator []`, indexed with a Custom type object, `algorithm_id` as dictated by its signature

The *array* `[]` access returns a pointer(either regular or smart pointer) to an object that has the member function `mesh()` which returns a pointer to `geodesic::Mesh` object.

The return value of `algorithms[algorithm_id]` was not `binded` to anything, rather, *held* as a temporary (if its not already a reference); then its member function, `mesh()` is called